# Redis maximum value size for single hash key

Tags: redis

In Redis,I have to store many fields under a single hash key. The number of fields may goes on increasing. Is there is any size limit for a single hash key? What will happen if I store more number of fields under a single key?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The limits are: 2^64 - 1 for 64 bits and 2^32-1 for 32 bits, so practically it is the amount of RAM because the numbers are too big.
More details here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/eArHCH9kHKA